# having errors in a java function

Tags: java

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

/**
   Grocery shop class

*/

public class Grocery_shop extends JFrame
{
   private Grocery_items items;       // A panel for routine charge checkboxes
   private quantitypanel qty; // A panel for quantity
   private JPanel buttonPanel; // A panel for the buttons
   private JButton calcButton;         // Calculates everything
   private JButton exitButton;         // Exits the application

   /**
      Constructor
   */

   public Grocery_shop()
   {
      // Display a title.
      setTitle("Victor's Grocery Shop");

      // Specify what happens when the close button is clicked.
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


 // Create a NonRoutinePanel object.
      qty = new quantitypanel();
    //  qty.setBackground(Color.white);

      // Create a RoutinePanel object.
      items = new Grocery_items(qty);



      // Build the panel that contains the buttons.
      buildButtonPanel();

      // Add the panels to the content pane.
      add(items, BorderLayout.WEST);
      add(qty, BorderLayout.EAST);
      add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

      // Pack and display the window.
      pack();
      setVisible(true);
   }

   /**
      The buildButtonPanel method creates a panel containing
      buttons.
   */

   private void buildButtonPanel()
   {
      // Create a button to calculate the charges.
      calcButton = new JButton("Add Charges");

      // Add an action listener to the button.
      calcButton.addActionListener(new CalcButtonListener());

      // Create a button to exit the application.
      exitButton = new JButton("Exit");

      // Add an action listener to the button.
      exitButton.addActionListener(new ExitButtonListener());

      // Put the buttons in their own panel.
      buttonPanel = new JPanel();
      buttonPanel.add(calcButton);
      buttonPanel.add(exitButton);
   }

   /**
      CalcButtonListener is an action listener class for the
      calcButton component.
   */

   private class CalcButtonListener implements ActionListener
   {
      /**
         actionPerformed method
         @param e An ActionEvent object.
      */

      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
         double totalCharges; // Total charges

         // Create a DecimalFormat object to format output.
         DecimalFormat dollar = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");

         // Calculate the total charges
         totalCharges = items.getCharges(); 
                 //+ nonRoutine.getCharges();

         // Display the message.
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Total Charges: $" + 
                                             dollar.format(totalCharges));
      }
   } // End of inner class

   /**
      ExitButtonListener is an action listener class for the
      exitButton component.
   */

   private class ExitButtonListener implements ActionListener
   {
      /**
         actionPerformed method
         @param e An ActionEvent object.
      */

      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
         System.exit(0);
      }
   } // End of inner class

   /**
      The main method creates an instance of the JoesAutomotive
      class, causing it to display its window.
   */

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Grocery_shop grocery = new Grocery_shop();
   }
}
```

---

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

/**
   RoutinePanel class

*/

public class Grocery_items extends JPanel
{
   // Named constants for charges
   private final double Baked_Beans  = 0.35;
   private final double Cornflakes = 1.75;
   private final double Sugar = 0.75;
   private final double Tea_Bags = 1.15;
   private final double Instant_Coffee = 2.50;
   private final double Bread = 1.25;
   private final double Sausage = 1.30;
   private final double Eggs = 0.75;
   private final double Milk = 0.65;
   private final double Potatoes = 2.00;

 //  private quantitypanel qty; // A panel for quantity


   private JCheckBox baked_beans_box;     // Check box for baked_beans
   private JCheckBox CornflakesBox;       // Check box for cornflakes
   private JCheckBox SugarBox; // Check box for sugar box
   private JCheckBox Tea_Bags_Box;    // Check box for tea bag
   private JCheckBox Instant_Coffee_Box;    // Check box for Instant_Coffee_Box
   private JCheckBox Bread_Box;       // Check box for bread box
   private JCheckBox SausageBox;  // Check box for sausage box
   private JCheckBox eggbox;  // Check box for egg box
   private JCheckBox milkbox;  // Check box for milk
   private JCheckBox potatoesbox;  // Check box for potatoes

 //  private JTextField baked_beans_JT; 
   /**
      Constructor
   */

   public Grocery_items(quantitypanel qty)
   {
    this.qty = qty;
      DecimalFormat dollar = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");


      // Create the check boxes.
      baked_beans_box = new JCheckBox("Baked_Beans ($" +
                                dollar.format(Baked_Beans) + ")");



      CornflakesBox = new JCheckBox("Cornflakes ($" +
                              dollar.format(Cornflakes) + ")");
      SugarBox = new JCheckBox("Sugar ($" + 
                                    dollar.format(Sugar) + ")");
      Tea_Bags_Box = new JCheckBox("Tea Bags ($" + 
                                 dollar.format(Tea_Bags) + ")");
      Instant_Coffee_Box = new JCheckBox("Instant Coffee_Box ($" + 
                                 dollar.format(Instant_Coffee) + ")");
      Bread_Box = new JCheckBox("Bread Box ($" + 
                              dollar.format(Bread) + ")");
      SausageBox = new JCheckBox("Suasages ($" + 
                                   dollar.format(Sausage) + ")");
      eggbox = new JCheckBox("Eggs ($" + 
              dollar.format(Eggs) + ")");

      milkbox = new JCheckBox("Milk ($" + 
              dollar.format(Milk) + ")");
      potatoesbox = new JCheckBox("Potatoes ($" + 
              dollar.format(Potatoes) + ")");

      // Create a GridLayout manager.
      setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 1));

      // Create a border.
      setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Grocery Items"));

      // Add the check boxes to this panel.
      add(baked_beans_box);
      add(CornflakesBox);
      add(SugarBox);
      add(Tea_Bags_Box);
      add(Instant_Coffee_Box);
      add(Bread_Box);
      add(SausageBox);
      add(eggbox);
      add(milkbox);
      add(potatoesbox);

   }



   /**
      The getCharges method calculates the routine charges.
      @return The amount of routine charges.
   */

   public double getCharges()
   {
      double charges = 0;

      if (baked_beans_box.isSelected())
         charges += Baked_Beans * qty.getBeanqty();
      if (CornflakesBox.isSelected())
         charges += Cornflakes;
      if (SugarBox.isSelected())
         charges += Sugar;
      if (Tea_Bags_Box.isSelected())
         charges += Tea_Bags;
      if (Instant_Coffee_Box.isSelected())
         charges += Instant_Coffee;
      if (Bread_Box.isSelected())
         charges += Bread;
      if (SausageBox.isSelected())
         charges += Sausage;
      if (eggbox.isSelected())
          charges += Eggs;
      if (milkbox.isSelected())
          charges += Milk;
      if (potatoesbox.isSelected())
          charges += Potatoes;



      return charges;
   }
}
```

---

```
//import java.awt.LayoutManager;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
//import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
//import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class quantitypanel extends JPanel {
     private JTextField baked_beans_JT;     // JTextField box for baked_beans
       private JTextField Cornflakes_JT;       // JTextField box for cornflakes
       private JTextField Sugar_JT; // JTextField box for sugar box
       private JTextField Tea_Bags_JT;    // JTextField box for tea bag
       private JTextField Instant_Coffee_JT;    // JTextField box for Instant_Coffee_Box
       private JTextField Bread_JT;       // JTextField box for bread box
       private JTextField Sausage_JT;  // JTextField box for sausage box
       private JTextField egg_JT;  // JTextField box for egg box
       private JTextField milk_JT;  // JTextField box for milk
       private JTextField potatoes_JT;  // JTextField box for potatoes


       public quantitypanel()
       {

           //create JTextField.
           baked_beans_JT = new JTextField(5);
           Cornflakes_JT = new JTextField(5);
           Sugar_JT = new JTextField(5);
           Tea_Bags_JT = new JTextField(5);
           Instant_Coffee_JT = new JTextField(5);
           Bread_JT = new JTextField(5);
           Sausage_JT = new JTextField(5);
           egg_JT = new JTextField(5);
           milk_JT = new JTextField(5);
           potatoes_JT = new JTextField(5);


           //initialize text field to 0
           baked_beans_JT.setText("0");
           Cornflakes_JT.setText("0");
           Sugar_JT.setText("0");
           Tea_Bags_JT.setText("0");
           Instant_Coffee_JT.setText("0");
           Bread_JT.setText("0");
           Sausage_JT.setText("0");
           egg_JT.setText("0");
           milk_JT.setText("0");
           potatoes_JT.setText("0");

         public double getBeanqty(){

             return Double.parseDouble(baked_beans_JT.getText());
         }


           //set Layout manager
           setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 1));

           //create border and panel title

          setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Amount"));

          //add text fields to the panel.
          add(baked_beans_JT);
          add(Cornflakes_JT);
          add(Sugar_JT);
          add(Tea_Bags_JT);
          add(Instant_Coffee_JT);
          add(Bread_JT);
          add(Sausage_JT);
          add(egg_JT);
          add(milk_JT);
          add(potatoes_JT);


       }



}
```

i'm having problems with the `items = new Grocery_items(qty);`

so therefore in the code every place that got qty has an error message attached to it. Please help

When the baked beans check box is selected, i want the number inputted into the jtextfield (Beanqty) to be multiplied by the baked beans checkbox.

thanks.

Comment: Did you import quantitypanel?

Comment: What is the error message? Error messages contain a lot of information about the cause of the problem. Try to understand what the error message says, and at least post the exact error message here. Just saying "there is an error message" is not helpful.

Comment: Post an SSCCE for better help sooner.

Comment: Actually it doesn't compile because the field `qty` is commented in the second class... Sure, that *this* code creates runtime errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a compile error in the `Grocery_Items` class. You've commented the `qty` field:

```
// private quantitypanel qty; // A panel for quantity
```

Remove the comment

```
private quantitypanel qty; // A panel for quantity
```

and you won't have any more *error messages attached to it [qty]*.

Comment: the error massage says "The constructor Grocery_items(quantitypanel) is undefined"